# Is there a downloadable package of eclipse which i can use for Java, c++ & JS

Tags: java, javascript, c++, eclipse, apache-flex

I am trying to download eclipse. And I am given lot of options in terms of packages.

I see different packages for java, c++ and JS.

Is there one package that i can install with which I can develop applications in all these? and also preferrably build applications using flex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rest of the information has already been mentioned, it is easy to get the bulk of the languages.  Flex can be achieved using the Air Gear plugin.  It is quite nice and very customizable for the use of the new versions of the SDK.  Software such as FDT is also built on the eclipse platform and can also be downloaded as an eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Virtually everything in Eclipse is a plugin, which means you can install new features into an existing Eclipse instance. For example, start with the **IDE for Java Developers** package or the **IDE for C/C++ Developers** package, then install the additional features you want. On the downloads page, right-hand side, there are links titled "Install Guide" and "Updating Eclipse," both of which will lead to information about installing additional features.

As for Flex, that's a tool provided by Adobe and I haven't tried installing it into an existing Eclipse package (first thing to check is whether Adobe provides an update site from which you could install). Another option would be to install the Flex tool as your "base" package and then add the Java, C/C+, JS, etc features from the eclipse.org update sites.

Answer (score -1):

If you install each of the packages, you can have Java, and C++ projects in your workspace, and you can have Java, C++, and javascript files in your projects.  So, in other works, install all the packages you want to use, they are integrated to work with each other.

Comment: thanks. Just to clarify, I have to download all the packages (jave, c++, JS) and install them all individually right?
Also, can i develop using flex in there or does it require any other plugin?

Comment: No, downloading each package will not integrate them together.

Comment: @E-Riz, what I meant was, you can have a Java project, and add a C++ file.  You can have a workspace with a Java project and a C++ project.  The elipse IDE allows the packages to be fairly integrated.  As integrated as you want to be.

Comment: @MarlinPierce, but that's not what your answer says. Installing the packages does NOT integrate them; installing one package and then adding features to it, does. The difference is important, as evidenced by AMM's response to your answer. You could edit your answer to be more clear what you mean.

Answer (score -1):

If you're confused see page: [Eclipse compare](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php)

But if you want for example develop applications only for Flex - download package that has minimum plugins and after Eclipse download - install plugin for Flex. <strike>The reason for that is faster initialization of Eclipse - the more plugins you have the more time you spend waiting for Eclipse to initialize.</strike> (As @E-Riz noted Eclipse loads bundles lazily as stated [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Lazy_Start_Bundles) - also look at the @E-Riz comment)

If you want `general` use package "for Java" I recommend download `Java EE` that have as much plugins for developement.

The answer depends on your needs - if you will develop applications using only Flex then you shouldn't download "everything" - you should download all that you **need**.

The Eclipse Core is only "small" package of OSGi - the rest is just plugins. The compare tha t you see in [Eclipse compare](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php) are packages that contains different set of plugins. You can install them after downloading "smaller plugins set'-Eclipse. There is no difference.

Comment: Eclipse uses a lazy-loading architecture, so having plugins installed does NOT mean it will take longer to load or "initialize" - plugins are only loaded when their functionality is actually invoked. Eclipse is specifically designed to avoid that problem.

Comment: E-Riz, can you suggest whats the best way forward?

Comment: Thanks for information. I thought that Eclipse loads all in initialization (I have known that NetBeans loads lazily) - this is from my personal experience. For example I installed several plugins (Aptana Rails, Hibernate Tools, JBoss Tools, etc.) and Eclipse started loading slowly.

Comment: @Xeon unfortunately it is possible to design or build a plugin poorly such that it impacts startup time. I dare say that none of the official Eclipse projects (those under the eclipse.org umbrella) do that, but third-party tools are not always as well designed.

Comment: @E-Riz that's probably the reason that my Eclipse load so slowly comparing it from beginning.

Comment: @Xeon, in my experience, Aptana is a heavy beast. I'd suggest disabling that first to see if performance improves.